# ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute when using register with variable name

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

ansible 2.7.4

Below works:

```
tasks:
    - name: Launch instance
      ec2:
         key_name: "{{ keypair }}"
         .
         .
      register: ec2

    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
        groupname: launched
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

But below doesn't

```
tasks:
        - name: Launch instance
          ec2:
             key_name: "{{ keypair }}"
             .
             .
          register: "{{ register }}"

        - name: Add new instance to host group
          add_host:
            hostname: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
            groupname: launched
          with_items: "{{ register.instances }}"
```

It results in:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute 'instances'"}
```

Not sure if it is related to this:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19803

Many thanks for the replies

Comment: I don't hear the problem: the issue you pointed to clearly says it's not supported behavior. But, even if it was, what you would want is actually (if such a thing were possible) `{{ {{register}}.instances }}` because `register` is not the **variable** it's the **expression** containing the name of the variable. The very fact that you even have to come to SO and ask this question means you are going to make someone's life harder who has to work with this code

Comment: Hey Matthew, thanks for the input. All help from the community to help a fellow colleague grow is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Registered dynamically named variables are not templatable yet in ansible.